# How to run a PHP file with a different header set

Tags: php

So the main file is using hstandard header for CORS, but the next file has an image header.

I already tried to include, require and shell_exec

```
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Cache-Control, Pragma, Authorization, Accept, Accept-Encoding");
```

The thing is, I don't have access to the front-end of the app for creating new Axios request. I also can't run CRON because the code needs to be executed every 5 seconds.

So, the only thing I can do is run the script from a PHP file, but on a separate background.

Comment: I have no idea what actual problem you are trying to solve here. _“So main file are using hstandard header for CORS but next file got image header.”_ - next what? Totally unclear what is going on. Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then try and give us a proper description of what you are trying to do, and where in that process what exact problem occurs.

Comment: i have 2 php files. 1 file with headers like in question next one with img header... if i use include we got error.  becouse of header

Comment: so 1 file sending json data as respond next one create image.  when include image file, we have no json output but only image were send...

Comment: Please don’t give such fragmentary explanations in comments, edit your question instead. And please go and actually read [ask] (because right now, it does not give the impression you actually did.) Don’t mention that you “got error” - explain what the error actually is, and quote error messages verbatim.